# Include JS (& CSS) Tags in emitted HTML from Nunjucks Plugin (or Loader)

Tags: webpack, nunjucks

When using html-webpack-plugin, the plugin can inject the JS Tags (as well as other tags, such as CSS, etc.).

When attempting to use nunjucks-webpack-plugin (et al), I would like to have the same level of convenience.

However, when I use nunjucks-webpack-plugin (et al), I can't seem to find a way to get Webpack to inject the script tags.

I am admittedly new to using Webpack, so I am probably missing something fundamental.

I've tried various Plugins and Loaders, in various chain orders.

Loaders and Plugins used:
- nunjucks-loader
- super-nunjucks-loader
- nunjucks-webpack-plugin

Here is an example of the kind of chaining that I would like to use:

```
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const NunjucksWebpackPlugin = require("nunjucks-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  // ...
  entry: {
    index: "./src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "[name].[hash].js"
  },
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new NunjucksWebpackPlugin({
      templates: [
        {
          from: "./src/index.njk",
          to: "_temp_.html"
        }
      ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "_temp_.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      chunks: ["index"]
    })
  ]
  // ...
};
```

The result would be the compiled Nunjucks Template's HTML, with the Javascript Script Tag () injected before .

Comment: There is a [simple-nunjucks-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-nunjucks-loader) (I'm the author) that is compatible with html-webpack-plugin (see example in docs).

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for `nunjucks-webpack-plugin`

> webpack compilation variables are also sent through to the template under the `__webpack__` object: `hash`

We can use something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/index.{{ __webpack__.hash }}.js"></script>
```